# MS Access SQL Query unmatched rows from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say I have Table_A and Table_B with following rows:

```
Table_A:

ID   PART_ID   KIT_ID
---------------------
1    1         340
2    12        340
3    19        340
4    30        340
5    1         348
6    19        348
7    27        348
...

Table_B:

PART_ID   REQ
-------------
1         Y
12        Y
19        Y
27        Y
30        Y
...
```

How do I get the following result in Table_C?

```
Table_C:

PART_ID   KIT_ID
----------------
27        340
12        348
30        348
...
```

I've tried the Query Wizard with the Unmatched Rows and for some reason cannot get any results that resemble what I need.. E.g., a customer orders a kit and each kit contains a bunch of parts (some required and some not); how do I find the missing parts for each kit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate all combinations for the kits and the parts, then filter out the ones that don't exist:

```
select k.kit_id, p.part_id
from (select distinct kit_id from table_a) as k,  -- no cross join in MS ACCESS
     table_b p
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_a as a
                  where a.kit_id = k.kit_id and a.part_id = p.part_id 
                 );
```

You may need the condition `REQ = "Y"` in the outer `where` clause.  I'm not sure if that is important.